# I want to make a video with ffmpeg starting from filenames which are not imd%04d

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a list of .png images, with the following format:

```
cut-x%2.2f-A.png
```

so for example

```
cut-x0.10-A.png
cut-x0.20-A.png
...
cut-x12.10-A.png
```

I try to launch `ffmpeg` as it follows:

```
ffmpeg -i "cut-x%2.2d-A.png" cuts.wmv
```

and I get the error:

> cut-x%2.2d-A.png: No such file or directory

Advice?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: My os, so my system is linux

Answer (score 0):

Use glob [pattern type](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" output.wmv
```

This will present your images in the same order of `ls -m1 *.png`.